# python Insert tupule value to mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I need to install tupule value to database,but getting ***"Unknown column 'Mac' in 'field list'"*** error
Below is the code i used

```
import  mysql.connector, csv, sys
conn  = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="root",
  database="mydjangoapp",
  port=3307,

)
cursor=conn.cursor()
t1=('Mac', 'Mohan')
sql="insert into books (title,isbn)  values(%s,%s)" %t1

cursor.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `%` interpolation, use placeholders.

```
t1 = ('Mac', 'Mohan',)
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO books (title, isbn) VALUES (%s, %s)", t1)
```

Comment: My error got removed,but no value is inserted in database

Comment: You'll have to commit too. `conn.commit()`.